# Where do I store metadata of NFT

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

Smart contract execution needs gas fee.
So all data can't be stored in blockchain.
Images could be stored on ipfs like Pinata.

Do I have to develop extra backend code to maintain information like "like/dislike", "favorite", "review", "nft collection" ...?
I am going to use Laravel and do you think it's a right decision?

Comment: Yes you can use a DB to store data off chain. It's a popular thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the metadatas at database with a 'json' column.